# User is listed under User Profile Service but not listed in the Select Users dialog for Workflow Email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, user-profile-service

I have confirmed that my User Profile Service have a user 'kamalpreet' with email 'kamalpreet@company.com'.

In InfoPath user also able to select the user from the People Picker control. No problem at all till this point.

In workflow, when we type `Send Email to these users` and try to select the user  'kamalpreet', I cannot see this name in the list. However most of the users are present.

Even if I try to get this name from the People Picker, the workflow fails with exception `Value cannot be null`

What could be the reason of this?